# Combining Date and Hour in where Condition to create conditional selection in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, date, conditional-statements, hour

The code below shows the DataX values for 4 hours before and now and 1 hour later. 
For example, hour is now 14 and we see the DataX values for 10-11-12-13-14-15 for today. 
My problem is that when hour becomes for ex 0:00, because of the fact that Date condition is adjusted for today, therefore I can't see the yesterday's 20-21-22-23 values. At one time, I just wanna see 6 values, 4 hours before, now and 1 hour later. How can i achieve it ?

```
SELECT 
    Hour as Saat,
    DataX
FROM CPS.dbo.CMM
Where Date = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102) and PowerPlantName in ('X') and Hour in (DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()),DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())-1,DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())-2,DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())-3,DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())-4,DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a `DATETIME` value from your date and hour hour columns - `DATEADD(HOUR, [Hour], [Date])`, then you can use a normal inequality operator to find where this datetime is greater than 4 hours ago, and less than one hour ahead:

```
SELECT  Hour as Saat,
        DataX
FROM    CPS.dbo.CMM
WHERE   PowerPlantName in ('X') 
AND     DATEADD(HOUR, [Hour], [Date]) >= DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE())
AND     DATEADD(HOUR, [Hour], [Date]) <= DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think second inequality should be `<` rther than `>` :)

Comment: When I run it, I got all the days' values but i dont want them. 
Now hour is 15. I just want to see today's 11-12-13-14-15-16 values.
If hour is 23 then i want to see today's 19-20-21-22-23 and tomorrow's 0 values.
If it is 1 then i want to see yesterday's 21-22-23 and today's 0,1 and 2.

Comment: @uguryigit93 Please try now, I have updated a typo in the where clause

Comment: I just understood the logic, that worked great thanks.